# Receber dados de uma url (m3u) usando php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho a seguinte Dúvida:

Tenho essa URL: `http://Infinity.quor8.com:8000/get.php?username=wesleybr&password=mxViBCIK05&type=m3u_plus&output=ts`

Ao acessar ela pelo navegador é feito o download de um arquivo .m3u até ai tudo bem :)

Eu preciso colocar essa url em um campo input e ao aperta o botão carregar abaixo alguns dados que estão dentro desse arquivo, como por exemplo:

`tvg-logo` `tvg-name` e todas as urls com final .ts

Gostaria de mostrar isso em forma de lista tipo:

`Nome`     `Logo`    `Url`

Não sei por onde começar, na verdade já tentei muitas coisas que nem vale colocar aqui :/ se alguém puder dar uma luz :)

Comment: Eu acho que nunca é uma boa ideia passar Usuários e Senhas por `GET`....

Comment: @MatheusCuba o problema maior é passar por http em vez de https. Sem https, tanto POST quanto GET passam as senhas em aberto. O POST só aparenta um pouco mais discreto, mas a diferença não é tanta quanto o pessoal pensa. O GET só piora um pouco por causa do historico, mas só trocar por POST não é solução real.

Comment: Certo, mas nesse caso eu só preciso listar em forma de tabela os dados que coloquei ali acima, não vou passar os dados do usuário e sim carregar os dados que preciso que estão no arquivo dessa url

Comment: @Bacco Eu concordo plenamente contigo, mas mesmo assim requisições `POST` apesar de serem tão expostas como requisições `GET`, são ainda que pouco, mais seguras. Não são todos os Usuários que possuem o conhecimento necessário para interceptar seus dados. É extremamente necessário o uso de certificado SSL para segurança, mas deixar uma requisição de login com GET? Qualquer Usuário de esquina pode copiar a URL e sair usando

Comment: Eu sei Metheus, mas acho que você não entendeu o ponto. Não importa se vai ter login e sneha na url, oq preciso é pegar os dados do arquivo que essa url baixa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A forma mais fácil é utilizando a função [preg_match_all](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) com `Regex`.

#### Capturando a lista através do cURL

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://Infinity.quor8.com:8000/get.php?username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD&type=m3u_plus&output=ts");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $response;
```

Utilizando esse código, você conseguirá capturar todo o conteúdo do arquivo e armazenar na variável `$response`.

É importante que você utiliza opções como `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`, `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`, `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` etc. Alguns servidores bloqueam o acesso quando não há determinados `headers`.

#### Filtrando o conteúdo do arquivo

Como eu mencionei no início, para filtrar você terá que utilizar `regex`.

```
<?php

preg_match_all('/((?:tvg-name)="(?<name>.*?)".+(?:tvg-logo)="(?<logo>.*?)".+\n(?P<link>https?:?\/\/.+))/', $response, $result, PREG_SET_ORDER);

$data = reset($result);
```

> `(?:tvg-name)="(?<name>.*?)"` - Aqui ele vai capturar todo o conteúdo envolvido pelas " (aspas) que venha após `tvg-name=`

> `.+(?:tvg-logo)="(?<logo>.*?)"` - O `.+` é para ele percorrer todo o conteúdo até `tvg-logo="` e capturar o conteúdo de entre as " (aspas)

> `.+\n(?P<link>https?:\/\/.+)` - Aqui o `.+` é a mesma coisa que o passo anterior, a diferença está no `\n` que significa percorrer, inclusive, uma quebra de linha e capturar toda a linha que comece com `http` ou `https`

> O `?:` no início dos parentes informa para não capturar aquele termo. Nessa expressão ele é opcional.

> Por fim, `(?<name>.*?)` informa para capturar todo o valor e transformar em um grupo com o nome `name`

Isso irá lhe retornar um `array` com os dados de *nome*, *logo* e *link*. Agora você pode fazer um `foreach` e exibir os dados em uma tabela.

#### Código completo

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://Infinity.quor8.com:8000/get.php?username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD&type=m3u_plus&output=ts");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if (substr($info["http_code"], 0, 2) != 20) {
    die("Could not connect to server. Check username and password");
}

preg_match_all('/(tvg-name="(?<name>.*?)".+tvg-logo="(?<logo>.*?)".+\n(?P<link>https?:\/\/.+))/', $response, $channels, PREG_SET_ORDER);

?>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Logo</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Link</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($channels as $channel): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="<?php echo $channel["logo"] ?>" height="75" width="75" /></td>
            <td><?php echo $channel["name"] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo str_replace(".ts", ".m3u8", $channel["link"]) ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Você também pode customizar com `css`:

```
<style>
    .channel {
        float:left;
    }
</style>

<div id="channels">
<?php foreach($channels as $channel): ?>
    <div class="channel">
        <a href="<?php echo str_replace(".ts", ".m3u8", $channel["link"]) ?>" title="<?php echo $channel["name"] ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $channel["logo"] ?>" height="75" width="75" alt="<?php echo $channel["name"] ?>" />
        </a>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

---

Caso queira substituir um valor enquanto adiciona os dados na tabela, basta utilizar `preg_replace` ou `str_replace`.

Comment: Caraaa Muito obrigado, você simplesmente solucionou meu problema, isso foi fantástico :)

Comment: Amigo, após vc editar parou de funcionarm oq aconteceu ?

Comment: @AndréLuizMardonis apenas removi o usuário e senha da URL

Comment: Desculpe kkk acabei de ver isso, amigo vê se consegue me ajudar em mais uma coisa, percebe que os links são .ts tem alguma forma de verificar isso e quando for .ts substituir para .m3u8 ?

Comment: @AndréLuizMardonis, editei minha resposta com essa opção.

Comment: Muito Obrigado amigo, agora consigo continuar :)

Comment: como eu poderia fazer uma estrutura de tabela dessa forma aqui: http://prntscr.com/i1r4n3 com a logo o nome abaixo e por fim o link ?

Comment: @AndréLuizMardonis, editei minha resposta. Como trabalho muito com `front-end`, fiz algo bem básico, só para ter uma noção.

Comment: Obrigado @Valdeir, para finalizar com sua ajuda(prometo kk) como eu faria para ao clicar na logo abrir um iframe acima dos canais passando para esse iframe o link do canal clicado e recebendo no arquivo do iframe que é o player.php, para que eu possa reproduzir esse canal ? dentro do player.php eu tenho um <script> onde devo receber o link do canal na source:

Comment: Como é uma pergunta diferente do post, resolvi postar em um lugar separado. https://pastebin.com/TxS2vYaL Depois posta o link do site para assistirmos =D

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71829/discussion-between-andre-luiz-mardonis-and-valdeir-psr).

Comment: vou colocar minha pergunta aqui pois pode ajudar algum colega. Links com redirecionamento não estão funcionando ai vc disse para usar curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); porém mesmo usando essa linha o problema continua :/

Comment: @Valdir Psr -- cara, estou com um problema na hora de abrir o popup do canal, simplesmente parou de funcionar de ontem pra hoje, pode ajudar ?

Answer (score -1):

Cara só vc gerar com o m3u8 mesmo, copia toda lista de canal joga no bloco de notas clicar em localizar e substituir o .m3u8 pelo .ts